# Why I cannot access certain IPs after changing AP mobile phone?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, android

When using my smartphone as access point (AP) for my PC, I cannot access certain page while I still can access then directly from this smartphone.

This started to happen when I switched from Samsung Galaxy A3 to Sony XPeria XA2. This does not happen when use a different AP.

I found that hostnames are correctly resolved to the same IP both on my smartphone and PC.

However, the problem seems on a routing level:

```
tracert 151.101.193.69

Tracing route to 151.101.193.69 over a maximum of 30 hops
1 * * * Request timed out.
2 * * * Request timed out.
3 * * * Request timed out.
4 * * * Request timed out.
5 * * * Request timed out.
6 * * * Request timed out.
7 * * * Request timed out.
8 * * * Request timed out.
9 * * * Request timed out.
10 * 192.168.43.6 reports: Destination net unreachable.
```

What could be the reason and how can I diagnose it?

Comment: Seems like an issue with your Sony Phone, you might want to contact Sony if no one here has any solutions for you.

Comment: @Sickest This does not happen when I access via old phone or via LTE modem. Yep, I Will need to contact Sony support forum as well.

Comment: I would also check your phones settings and see if there are like firewall related functions. It's a longshot, but who knows. I've never personally played with a Sony Phone.